# Passed this not accessed using arrow functions

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I was trying to implement  mongoose virtual getter :

```
   UserSchema.virtual('fullName')
   .get(function () {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
})
```

I have noticed that when I use es6 arrow function instead of the normal anonymous function as a parameter to the the get the virtual getter would return undefined.

I know that arrow functions keeps the context of `this` but where is the `this` that the normal anonymous function is using?.
if it was passed by *.bind* or using the *call()/apply()* functions then it shouldn't matter if it is arrow function or normal(that's what I tested atleast). So why is this only working with normal functions but not arrow functions?.

Comment: Yes, I know.
But this arrow function does not work. The one I typed is the one that works. And why does that happen is my question.

Comment: Gotcha. Off the top of my head it's about applying to the model instance, but I suppose a full explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` that the normal anonymous function is using is being provided by `get()`.

If you use an arrow function, you are binding `this` yourself, which means it's bound to the `this` in your function that calls `get()`.

You would see the same thing happen if you called

```
.get((function() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}).bind(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that arrow functions keeps the context of this

They do. It is like using `function () { ... }.bind(this)`.

> but where is the this that the normal anonymous function is using?

It depends on [how the function is **called**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

That is done by some other code deep inside the `get` function which you aren't currently looking at.

Since the function clearly makes use of `this`, that context **matters**.

> if it was passed by .bind

… then you'd have the same problem as the arrow functions.

> or using the call()/apply() functions

… then it would be called immediately rather than when you need it to be called.

> then it shouldn't matter if it is arrow function or normal

It would matter. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function has a special binding for **this** that is coming from its lexical context.

> if it was passed by .bind or using the call()/apply() functions then it shouldn't matter if it is arrow function or normal(that's what I tested atleast).

I tested it myself and the arrow function take precedence over `call`:

```
function f () { var f = () => console.log(this.a); f.call({a: 2});}
f.call({a: 3})
> 3
```

The logic behind this behavior probably could be understood from this quote from the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> An ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for arguments, super, **this**, or new.target. Any reference to arguments, super, **this**, or new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment.

If arrow function does not have its own binding for **this** then bind/call/apply/etc. have no effect on its **this** binding.